# Pop a client form byclicking an asp.net button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I want to pop up a form by an asp.net button. In the form there are several text box to be filled. And also there are "Save" and "Cancel" buttons. Once "Save" is clicked, the data filled will save into database and the screen goes back to the original one and refreshed.

I heard that it is impossible. In another word, mixing up clien side and server side codeing is a daydream.

Any idea or alternative way on pure server side?
Thanks.

Comment: It's completely possible using AJAX and the technologies you have specified as tags. But this is not a "give me teh codez" website. Have you tried anything?

Comment: For the pop-up part, do you want it to open in a div inside the current page or you wanted completely open in a pup-up window?

Comment: I don't know what plugin is suitable. I want completely open a new pop-up window.

Comment: Have you read this **http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx** ??

Comment: It's definitely possible, you definitely want the AJAX Control Toolkit. You (probably) won't need jQuery.

Comment: Actually I forgot mention it. It is a SharePoint application page. I just ask for asp.net. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be easily achieved using jQuery and [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) jQuery plugin. Checkout the [Plugin Demo](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) on their website and under "Other Content Types" section you'll find examples that will help you in your implementation. Hope this helps.